# How to GROUP and choose lowest value in R

Tags: r

Assuming below data

```
OriginId, OriginName, DestinationId, DestinationName,Time
1        ,   Origin 1,   1       ,          Destination 1 , 20
1        ,   Origin 1,   2       ,          Destination 2 , 25
2        ,   Origin 2,   3       ,          Destination 3 , 14
2        ,   Origin 2,   4       ,          Destination 4 , 29
```

This is a CSV which holds travel time between origins and destinations. I want to find the closest destination per origin. In other words, I have to group the data by OriginId and give rank to each group based on the time and get those rows which got rank 1. So the desired result for above data is:

```
OriginId, OriginName, DestinationId, DestinationName,Time(Minute)
1        ,   Origin 1,   1       ,          Destination 1 , 20
2        ,   Origin 2,   3       ,          Destination 3 , 14
```

Which R function do I need to use after group by?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, can group by 'OriginId' and then get the row index of 'Time' that has the minimum 'Time' with `which.min`, extract that row with `slice`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(OriginId) %>%
  slice(which.min(Time))
```

---

Or, if we consider to use `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'OriginId', we get the row index (as in the previous case) and subset the rows  of the dataset (`.SD`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[which.min(Time)], by = OriginId]
```

Comment: Thanks, would that be possible to add a bit details to your answer?

Comment: @shaahin Sorry, there was some problem with javascript on my browser which prevented me to update with description.  Now, it is updated.